# How to display a custom link in rails admin index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I am having a Rails 3.2 Application which is using "Rails Admin" for admin functionality.

My doubt is, "How can I display an extra link beside the default CRUD options for a particular model (Like User model) in its index page". By clicking on that link, I would like to perform a custom action from my controller (Like UsersController).

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve the above mentioned case, or provide a reference url.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

K. Subrahmanyam

Answer (score 0):

For getting an extra link in the index page of a particular model, first I installed rails_admin gem into the vendor folder of my application, instead of installing it normally.

Then, after the "last_links" available in "index.html.haml" within rails_admin related views, I added an if condition to check my required model name by using the abstract_model parameter available there. Then, I added my new link after my if condition.

Hope, it may help someone.

Regards,

K. Subrahmanyam